# Listener for counter until variable changing

Tags: java, listener

Is there a way to build listener that detect if date are still transmitted to variable and if yes do one thing and when not do other?

For example

Until “int counter1” increasing set boolean (true) or print or change another int for 1

int counter (not increasing or decreasing anymore)  set Boolean (false)  print different thing change another int for 2.

Basically variable changing plus or minus do one thing stop changing do other thing start changing again go back to doing first thing etc etc.

Is there a way to do this?
Without obvious whole if statements compering way.

Comment: Its really unclear what you are trying to achieve. Could you give some more background, or even better, show us some (pseudo)code of what you are trying to achieve. (Even if its with the _'obvious whole if statements compering way'_)

Comment: How do you define 'stop changing'?  Did you have an interval in mind (1 second for example) which if has occurred with no change, it means that it's 'stopped changing'?

Comment: Ok. I getting some data to variable ok let say to integer.
Data keep coming like in counter 1, 2, 3, 4,… etc. 
Until this data coming and integer value changing I want to one thing to happen.
For example triggered Boolean print something out etc.
Moment this int value stop changing stopped I want listener to detect that it is stopped changing.
And do something else. Again when number start changing again I want listener to detect that and do first thing again

Comment: @ user2478398 I want this to be triggered by value change. No matter if it increase or decrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Handmade

Most simple way is to access that variable through getters and setters. You can put preferred logic into your setter and track all mutations from there.

```
public class Main {

    static int observable = 0;

    static void setObservable(int newValue) {
        if (observable != newValue) {
            System.out.printf("Observable int has been changed from %d to %d.%n", observable, newValue);
            observable = newValue;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        observable = 1; // Nothing notified us that value has been changed

        setObservable(2); // Console output 'Observable int changed from 1 to 2.'
    }
}
```

### Built-in solutions

There are plenty other ways to implement the same functionality: create actual java bean with getters and setters, implement [observable and observer interfaces](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258/learn-java/observer-and-observable.html) on your own or use ready built-in solutions, for example `IntegerProperty`:

```
    IntegerProperty intProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    intProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

        if (!oldValue.equals(newValue) ) {
            System.out.printf("Value has been changed from %d to %d!%n", oldValue.intValue(), newValue.intValue());
        }
    });

    intProperty.setValue(1); // Output: Value has been changed from 0 to 1!
    intProperty.setValue(2); // Output: Value has been changed from 1 to 2!
    intProperty.setValue(2); // No output

    System.out.println(intProperty.intValue()); // Output: 2
```

### stopped changing

As for "stopped changing" listener, it's a little bit more complex issue. Depending on exact situation, there are several possible solutions I can think of:
1) if your loop is predictable and determined by you, just code the logic manually as it's required

```
/* listening for changes up there  */

System.out.println("I'll go get some coffee");
Thread.sleep(60000); // stopped changing, eh?

/* do your stuff */

/* Continue listening for changes below  */
```

2) if your loop is unpredictable but designed by you, you can try make it a little bit more predictable, design set of rules and protocols to follow, for example if new value is exactly zero, system will pause and switch to another task
3) you can also run background task which will periodically check last updated time, to determine if system is idle

There a lot of possible solutions to suggest, but I can't come up with something more specific without knowing more details

Comment: Basically I need this for travel app. So I getting distance values I want to know when did I stop so it can be save and when I start moving again so it can be save again

Comment: If you want to save your progress for both moving and idle cases, why bother connecting these two things? I would just save periodically regardless. In other case, If you are doing this to track route using android, try reading [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) article on location listeners and use `onLocationChanged` method.